# C# Parallel heavy process

Tags: c#, asynchronous, foreach, parallel-processing, queue

I have to execute a method 'x' times in parallel.This method basically calls SQL Server Reporting Services to generate a report, so I have a list of -say 200 reports- to generate.

The time consumed by the method (report generation) varies according to the input parameters received:sometimes will take 1 second, sometimes 50 seconds, 2 minutes, etc..

I have a collection of reports to generate (`_distinctReports`), so what I did is to call `Parallel.ForEach` sending the collection with a `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` = 8:

```
Parallel.ForEach(_distinctReports, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism =  _maxDegreeOfParallelism }, ExecuteReport);
```

I've observed that `Parallel.ForEach` calls somehow "batches" of 8 elements at once (according to the server CPU this may vary, but in the server I am testing, always 8 are being processed) and only sends another batch of 8 once the previous 8 are done, which is a big issue in my case, let me tell why:
If the batch contains 7 reports generated in 1 second each plus one report in 2 minutes, I have to wait 2 entire minutes until the next batch of 8 is triggered by `Parallel.ForEach`.

I would like to have a queue of 8 (of other desired amount) which is being filled conmtinously with more elements to process as soon as there are available slots (rather than blocks of 8).

How can I accomplish this in C#? I read about queues, but I could not come up with a design to fulfill my requirement.

Comment: "_This method basically calls SQL Server Reporting Services to generate a report_" Sounds like this should be asynchronous rather than parallel. Is `ExecuteReport` an `async` method?

Comment: No is not async. I'm considering that option, but remember I don't want to have more than 8 reports being processed at the same time

Comment: The concurrency of `async` can be restricted as well. If this is a process that involves I/O then you will obtain little benefit from parallelism.

Comment: Thanks @JohnathanBarclay, I will have a look. One thing more, the reports are generated in another server and they are normally small in size, but the logic to fetch the data at SSRS level can be very slow there, so not that much benefit in I/O operations.

Comment: AFAIK the `Parallel.ForEach` does not behave in the batching manner you describe. It behaves in the expected way. So something else is probably going on. Could you try calling `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100);` at the start of the program, to ensure that you are not throttled by the `ThreadPool` availability?